# Sub-array defined by list of indices

Tags: arrays, swift

What's the most straightforward way to select a subset of a given Swift array using an *arbitrary* collection of its indices?

For example, if `myArray = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]`, then `myArray[0..2]` will return `["first", "second", "third"]`. But apparently this sort of slicing only works for contiguous index ranges. I naively want something like `myArray[0, 2]` or `myArray[[0, 2]]` to return `["first", "third"]`, but I'm out of luck.

Which command am I looking for?

Comment: You could create `extension Array { subscript(_ indices: [Int]) -> Array<Element> { indices.map { self[$0] } } }`? Currently, if we see at the Array doc, there is `@inlinable public subscript(bounds: Range<Int>) -> ArraySlice<Element>` and the basic one with an index.

Comment: I think that `subscript` is a reserved keyword or something? Changing `subscript` to `func sub` this does the trick -- thanks.

Comment: You can use @Larme s solution. Tested it, works just fine.